# Strategies to GoogleDrive API limit export download 10 mb

Tags: google-drive-api, google-slides-api

We've been developing a solution which is responsible for generating a PPT with a lot of images embedded and then downloading in the browser via Google Slides and Google Drive API.

So, we discovered in the middle of the project that there's a limitation on the export of files from Google Drive API - currently at 10mb per file. Some PPT's are supposed to have thousand pics on them, so that's not ok for us.

Here's a sample of the method used for exporting and downloading the PPT file.

```
public byte[] downloadPPT() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    driveService.files().export(getPresentation().getPresentationId(),
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation").
           executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

    if (googleProperties.getRemovePresentationAfterDownload()) {
        driveService.files().delete(getPresentation().getPresentationId()).execute();
    }

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Does anyone has a suggestion of solution that can solve this, that keep us using Google API's?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to know your method for exporting files, can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your private information.

Comment: Of course, I will update my question, thanks !

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536507/downloading-a-google-slides-presentation-as-powerpoint-doc-using-google-apps-scr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export Google Slides without size limit you can use direct link for `pptx` version:

`GET https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<FILE_ID>/export/pptx`

Reference: https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/