# Downloading a Google Slides presentation as PowerPoint doc using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

The GUI of Google Slides offers to download a GSlides presentation as a Powerpoint (myFile.pptx). I could not find the equivalent in the Google Apps Script documentation - any pointer?

**EDIT**

Thanks to comments and answers, I tried this snippet:

```
function testFileOps() {
  // Converts the file named 'Synthese' (which happens to be a Google Slide doc) into a pptx
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Synthese');
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var blobPptx = file.getBlob().getAs('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation');
    var result = rootFolder.createFile(blobPptx);
  }
}
```

It returns an error:

> Converting from application/vnd.google-apps.presentation to
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
>   is not supported. (line 7, file "Code")

**SECOND EDIT**

As per another suggestion in comments, I tried to make an http call from Google App Script, that would directly convert the gslides into pptx, without size limit. It produces a file on G Drive, but this file is corrupted / unreadable. The GAS script:

```
function convertFileToPptx() {
  // Converts a public Google Slide file into a pptx
 var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Zc4-yFoUYONXSLleV_IaFRlNk6flRKUuAw8M36VZe-4/export/pptx');
 var blobPptx = response.getContent();
 var result = rootFolder.createFile('test2.pptx',blobPptx,MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT);
}
```

Notes:

- I got the mime type for pptx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc#4212908)
- using the mime type `'pptx'` returns the same error message

Comment: Export the file as a given mimetype. Note that since Apps Script doesn't run in your browser, you'll need to either do this as part of a webapp (return `downloadAsFile`) or create the effort file in Google Drive.

Comment: thx a lot! Any pointer as to which line of GAS would do the export? I couldn't find it in the online doc?

Comment: You need Drive Service or the Drive API (advanced service).

Comment: Edited the question with a code snippet. Does it correspond to the approach you recommend?

Comment: Thx. Changed the code accordingly in the OP. The error message shows it recognizes the Mime type of the gslides doc. But the error still occurs.

Comment: Try file.getAs() instead of file.getBlob.getAs() - Going to test this quickly. Getting the same error using this method: Converting from application/vnd.google-apps.presentation to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation is not supported. (line 6, file "Code") - My code is slightly modified as I am getting the file by ID instead of name.

Comment: There is answer for exporting Google Slides to pptx without size limit (which currently is 10 Mb): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50680468/555121

Comment: great! That http call must be done from outside of G Apps Script however... so you need a server somewhere. I'll read further, maybe GAS can make http calls, read the result (the pptx file) and save it to the drive. What a pain.

Comment: @seinecle If your issue was solved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be also useful for other users.

Comment: It is not solved, the trick to do it via an http call works only from outside Google Apps Script, which is not what I asked about. So far I'd say conversion to pptx from Google Apps Script is impossible

Comment: @seinecle Thank you for replying. I misunderstood about your situation. I'm really sorry. Can you provide your latest script? I would like to confirm it. If you can do, please add it to your question. By the way, about what you want, you want to convert from Google Slides to Microsoft powerpoint using Google Apps Script, and create it as a file in your Google Drive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly this.

Comment: @seinecle Thank you for quick reply . Can you provide your latest script? I would like to confirm it. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: edited the question with the script I used.

Comment: @seinecle Thank you for updating. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Did anything work? I am getting corrupt file or the similar error as well with my script too. Any solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998990/how-to-attach-google-slides-with-gmailapp-sendemail

Comment: Yes the accepted solution worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- `response.getContent()` returns byte array. So please use `response.getBlob()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function convertFileToPptx() {
  var fileId = "1Zc4-yFoUYONXSLleV_IaFRlNk6flRKUuAw8M36VZe-4";
  var outputFileName = "test2.pptx";

  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + fileId + '/export/pptx';
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var blobPptx = response.getBlob();
  var result = rootFolder.createFile(blobPptx.setName(outputFileName));
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to convert Google Slides, which are not published, in your Google Drive, please use access token. At that time please modify `url` as follows.

  - `var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + fileId + '/export/pptx?access_token=' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();`
- `DriveApp.createFile()` creates a file on root folder as the default.

#### References:

- [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)
- [getOAuthToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken)

Comment: works great. I thought I had tried getBlob() on the response but apparently not... And your additional comment on non public files is very useful, thx!!

Comment: @seinecle Thank you for quick reply. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by tehhowch, you could get the Google Slide file from your Drive and get it as a `.pptx`. (Not sure of mime type.)

[`File#getAs`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)):
[image]

Comment: ok I'll try it for G Slides => pptx specifically before accepting the answer

Comment: No rush, if it works please let me know. I will most likely need to use this in the future.

Comment: I added as snippet in the question.

Comment: if set contentType = 'pplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' - File#getAs will export to pptx

Answer (score 0):

I add all modifications with token part and specific folder

```
function convertFileToPptx() {
  var fileId = "Your File ID";
  var outputFileName = "name.pptx";

  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + fileId + '/export/pptx';
  //var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Your Folder ID")
  var params = {method:"GET", headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  var blobPptx = response.getBlob();
  var result = rootFolder.createFile(blobPptx.setName(outputFileName));
}
```

Comment: Could you exlain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the byte[] do:

```
function downloadAsPPTX(){

  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
     
  var fileId = presentation.getId();               
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + fileId + '/export/pptx';
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);      
  var blobPptx = response.getBlob();
   Logger.log("size: "+blobPptx.getBytes().length);

}
```