# When trying to convert ppt to Google Slide receive converting error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

In my google script program, I am trying to iterate over a folder and make all of the ppt files into google slide files.

```
function makeSlides(url) {
  slideUrls = []; 
  var id = getId(url);
  var powerPoints = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT);

  // turn ppt into slides
  while(powerPoints.hasNext()) {
    var powerPoint = powerPoints.next()
    try{
      var sheet = powerPoint.getBlob().getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES);
      DriveApp.getFolderById(url).createFile(sheet)
      Logger.log("OK " + powerPoint.getName());
    }catch(e) {
      Logger.log("ERROR: " + e) 
    }
 }
```

After checking the logs I get an error

> Exception: Converting from application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation to application/vnd.google-apps.presentation is not supported.

I know within the UI of Google Drive, you can open a ppt as a Google Slide. Is there any work around to this? Or am I doing it wrong?

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536507/downloading-a-google-slides-presentation-as-powerpoint-doc-using-google-apps-scr) but this is the opposite of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot convert from Powerpoint format to Google Slides using `getAs()`. You can achieve this using Drive API. In this modification, I used Drive API using Advanced Google Services.

**When you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about this at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737410).**

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var sheet = powerPoint.getBlob().getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES);
DriveApp.getFolderById(url).createFile(sheet)
```

To:

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: powerPoint.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES}, powerPoint.getBlob());
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, the converted file is created to the root folder. If you want to create in the specific folder, please modify from `{title: powerPoint.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES}` to `{title: powerPoint.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES, parents: [{id: folderId}]}`.
- If you want to retrieve the file ID from the converted file, please use `var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: powerPoint.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES}, powerPoint.getBlob()).id`.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)
- [Drive.Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.