# Can I export Google Slides as HTML in the Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm stuck implementing a prototype to extract Google slides for other processing. When I try `request = service_drive_v3.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/html)` on a Google slide I get:

`<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>/export?mimeType=text%2Fhtml&alt=media returned "The requested conversion is not supported.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'The requested conversion is not supported.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'convertTo'}]">`

The [Google Drive reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) says that Google slides can be exported to PDF and other formats including `text/plain` but not `text/html`.

However, `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<FILE_ID>/export/html` via a browser gives me a pretty nicely formatted HTML file just fine.

Is there a reason why the Drive API call fails even though Google seems to be able to export to HTML just fine? Is there a workaround.

Comment: Also be aware that there is 10 Mb limit for exported files via API, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50612407/555121 Fetching export URL result seems more productive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no endpoint to export Slides as HTML in the google-api library. The version you get in `/export/html` is the one generated as `{fileID}/pub` when you publish a presentation to the web. The workaround you have found is pretty good.

You might want to create a async function to retrieve the file by using an HTTP request. My recommendation is to fill up a feature request to make that functionality available on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features